# apply command to list of files in python

Tags: python, command, call

I've a tricky problem. I need to apply a specific command called `xRITDecompress` to a list of files with extension `-C_` and I should do this with Python.

Unfortunately, this command doesn't work with wildcards and I can't do something like:

```
os.system("xRITDecompress *-C_")
```

In principle, I could write an auxiliary bash script with a `for` cycle and call it inside my python program. However, I'd like not to rely on auxiliary files...

What would be the best way to do this within a python program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to get the list of files on which you want to run the command and then for each file in that list, run the command -

```
import glob
for f in glob.glob('*-C_'):
    os.system('xRITDecompress {}'.format(f))
```

From [documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob)

> The glob module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern according to the rules used by the Unix shell.

If by `_` (underscore) , you wanted to match a single character , you should use - `?` instead , like -

```
glob.glob('*-C?')
```

Please note, `glob` would only search in current directory but according to what you wanted with the original trial, seems like that maybe what you want.

---

You may also, want to look at [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module, it is a more powerful module for running commands (spawning processes). Example -

```
import subprocess
import glob
for f in glob.glob('*-C_'):
    subprocess.call(['xRITDecompress',f])
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with subprocess. The underscore is part of the extension "-C_": once decompressed, the filename ending becomes "-__".

Comment: Ok cool , will change the code in subprocess example for that.

Comment: @urgeo Also, I would like to suggest if the answer was helpful for you , you should accept them by clicking on the tick mark on the left side (whichever was most helpful for you) , it would be helpful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) or [`glob.iglob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) to get files that match the given pattern:

```
import glob

files = glob.iglob('*-C_')
for f in files:
    os.system("xRITDecompress %s" % f)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `glob.glob` to search and `os.system` to execute

```
import os
from glob import glob
for file in glob('*-C_'):
    os.system("xRITDecompress %s" % file)
```

I hope it satisfies your question